# Textfield client side validation

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I implement a validator that won't allow a use to type angled-brackets on the client side.

This, of course, only allows the use to type numbers:

```
{                       
xtype: 'numberfield',
hideTrigger: true,
name: 'tsId',
width: 120
}
```

But how would I have a textfield that allows a user to type anything other than angled-brackets. < >

Comment: You will have to define a custom validation type, and a custom regex to do this. regex like /[^\<\>]/ to not allow those 2 characters specifically... but if you need other restrictions it will be a lot more complex

Comment: @xcezzz just started doing/ learning javascript and sencha. But that makes sense.

Comment: sorry i wish i was up to snuff on my ext/sencha or I would provide more help on actual method to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is your friend - here's the expression you'll need to test against

```
/<|>/g
```

You can use it as a function like so:

```
var str;

function evaluate() {
    str = $('#evaluationText').val();
    var evalTest = str.match(/<|>/g); // test for '<' or '>'
    if(evalTest){
        alert('illegal chars..');
    }else {
        alert('all good');
    }
}

$('#evalText').click(function() {
  evaluate();
});
```

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ackerman/K6agg/